# VirtualBox upgrade trashed my virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I had Virtual Box 3.2 working fine, emulating 32-bit Windows XP in a 64-bit Windows 7 host. Then I upgraded to VirtualBox 4.0.4, and everything seemed to work (after I installed a couple of things -- USB2.0 support, Guest Additions).
Then I restored a snapshot that was taken under version 3.2, and now I've lost everything. I get the error message:

```
The selected virtual machine is *inaccessible*. Please inspect the error message shown
below and press the **Refresh** button if you want to repeat the accessibility check:

Could not find an open hard disk with UUID {b0e666ef-1041-415a-8329-876b337e1958}.
Result Code: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
Component: 
VirtualBox
Interface: 
IVirtualBox {d2de270c-1d4b-4c9e-843f-bbb9b47269ff}
```

I tried creating a new virtual machine from the vdi file, but it locks up when loading `WINDOWS\System32\DRIVERS\lfsfilt.sys`. I tried re-installing version 3.2, but I get exactly the same problems.

I have a `VirtualBox.xml` file in my `.VirtualBox` directory, and various files (Virtual Dell.xml, Virtual Dell.xml-prev etc.) in `.VirtualBox\Machines\Virtual Dell`.

Help please! How do I get my virtual machine back?

Comment: This should probably be posted at power users site?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: This question is not quite on topic for Stack Overflow, I'm reluctant to migrate it because it has an accepted and up-voted answer.

Comment: @Tim Post: You can't close this post without giving Terseus the 500 points that I owe! That is really not fair to Terseus.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This bug happened to me recently (I assume it's a VirtualBox bug) using snapshots in v4.

I fix'em opening the VirtualBox.xml file and:

1. Search the UUID of the missing drive (b0e666ef-1041-415a-8329-876b337e1958 in this case), normally will be a  tag (notice the />).
2. Remove the  tag which generate the error.
3. Now, if the problematic HardDisk tag was inside another HardDisk tag (one with open  and close  tag) reconvert this last tag in one without close.

Sorry, my english it's not good enough for a good explanation, let me show you an example:

Original non-working XML piece:

```
<HardDisks>
    <HardDisk uuid="{ac511969-288a-44b4-b7ac-df5808c1a4ca}" 
        location="/home/me/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/machine_name.vdi" 
        format="VDI" type="Normal">
        <HardDisk uuid="{e4e44e9d-aad0-4e2f-8ef8-d3d4d64f997f}" 
            location="/home/me/.VirtualBox/Machines/machine_name/Snapshots/{e4e44e9d-aad0-4e2f-8ef8-d3d4d64f997f}.vdi" 
            format="VDI"/>  <!-- Problematic snapshot -->
    </HardDisk>
</HardDisks>
```

Fixed XML piece:

```
<HardDisks>
    <HardDisk uuid="{ac511969-288a-44b4-b7ac-df5808c1a4ca}" 
        location="/home/me/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/machine_name.vdi" 
        format="VDI" type="Normal" /> <!-- Notice we've changed this tag and remove his closing tag since it's not more needed -->
</HardDisks>
```

This at least works for me, I loose the snapshot but recover the virtual machine.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I tried this, and it's looking good! Give me 24 hours, and if everything still works, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Terseus: I owe you 500 points, but the moderators closed the question before you got them. I will chase them up on this.

Comment: Yeah I've seen closing it about one hour before the bounty finish, as you stated it's not very fair but don't worry, it's not your fault and after all I already earned some points from this answer ^_^

Comment: @Terseus: Thanks for being so reasonable! I've posted on meta about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83411/question-closed-before-bounty-expired. We'll see if that helps.

Comment: @Terseus: I finally worked out how to do it :-)

Comment: @TonyK Wow, you made me jump off the chair when see my reputation :) thank you very much man, I no longer expect it.

Comment: A variant of this answer that worked for me was to alter the `machinename.xml` file:  Find the line with `<Image uuid="{…}"/>` for the corrupt snapshot UUID and merely replace it with the latest known-good snapshot's UUID (which appears elsewhere in the config, but that's apparently okay).  After restarting virtualbox, I was good to go.

Answer (score 2):

in Virtual Media Manager, is the XP VDI disk attached to the virtual machine? If it is not then open settings for the VM and add the VDI in the Storage tab

Comment: I can't find a Storage tab (I'm back to Virtual Box 4.0.4 now). If I click in "File|Virtual Media Manager", I get a dialog box, with tabs "Hard Disks", "CD/DVD Images", and "Floppy Images". In the "Hard Disks" tab, I see my VDI file. The status info at the bottom says: "Location: C:\MyDir\MyDisk.vdi; Type (Format): Normal (VDI); Attached to: Not Attached". If I expand the sub-tree under this, I get a list of items of the form "{0994df17-8874-4c85-8476-2757a829353c}.vdi"; these are small, and two of them have a warning triangle icon. None of them is the UUID in the original error message.

Comment: ok, in the settings of your Virtual Machine, have you got any VDI in the "Storage" tab, under IDE\SATA Controller ?

Comment: The original virtual machine doesn't get that far. I think maybe I should concentrate on the new virtual machine: the problem there is that it locks up when loading the `lfsfilt.sys` driver. This happens also during 'Safe Mode with Command Prompt' boot, so I can't get in to delete it. Oh, and I can't boot up from simulated floppies, because the whole disk is encrypted with TrueCrypt.

Comment: if deleting lfsfilt.sys solves the problem, this is what i would do: create a new WinXP VM with a new XP installation and two hard disks attached - the new installation VDI and old XP VDI. Then, I'd boot the new installation and delete the .sys file from the hard disk of the old VDI

Comment: <contd.> Then I'd add an entry in boot.ini to be able to boot from old XP VDI and see if it boots successfully. (after all, do you want access to the disk to delete the .sys?)

Answer (score 1):

another option is to plug in the ISO of [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) and use one of the Browsers / File Managers for disk access

the BootCD also has *mini* versions of Windows 98 + XP