# Finding the column and applying custom parser

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter plugin to do some custom sorting which works great. I set this parser to be on a specific column, but the application allows me to switch columns on and off though some settings, so the index of the column of this custom sorting can be different depending on the settings.

Is it possible to make it automatically finds the right column and use this parser method I got? Instead of manually placing it on the header index.

EDIT, right now I am using it like this (sometimes the "quarters" sorter can be at another index, so i need the code to auto detect it)

```
$("table").tablesorter({
                headers: {
                    0: { sorter: false },
                    1: { sorter: false },
                    5: { sorter: "quarters" }
                }
            });
```

And my custom parser:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'quarters',
        is: function (s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function (s) {
            var match = s.match(/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20\d\d)/);
            if (match)
            {
               return match[3] * 1000 - match[2] * 100 - match[1] * 10;                
            }
            else return 0;
        },
        type: 'text'
    });
```

Comment: can you show js code you are currently using

Comment: Would you mind if I used your question to transfer 500 bounty points to Terseus (the second responder below)? I owe these points for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209881/virtualbox-upgrade-trashed-my-virtual-machine/5247978#5247978. My question was closed as off-topic, so Terseus never got those bounty points. If you have no objection, I will offer a 500-point bounty for your question, and award it to Terseus' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some selector on the `th` that you want to apply the `quarters` sorter to then you could use jQuery to select that header, and then use `prevUtil` to get all of the `th` siblings before it and use that size to determine the index of the column you want.

My example assumes your column in question has an `id` of `quarters`:

```
var headerPosition = $("#quarters").prevUntil().size());
var headers = {};

headers[headerPosition] = "quarters";

$("table").tablesorter({
    headers: headers
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/7A3ZF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this small function to search the index of the header where you want to use the sort parser:

```
function get_index_by_text($list, text){
    var searched = -1;
    $list.each(function(index){
        if ($(this).text() == text) {
            searched = index;
            return(false);
        }
    });
    return(searched);
}

var quarters_index = get_index_by_text($("table thead th"), "quarters");
```

Just take care and check if the text is finded, if it's not the function will return -1.